# Сериализация списка JSON

Tags: c#, сериализация

Как сериализовать список Items в JSON?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    int poss = 10;
    List<String> Items = new List<string>();             

    public void addItem(string Text, bool Checked)
    {
        ToDo_Item item = new TestToDo.ToDo_Item(Text, Checked);
        visitor.Controls.Add(item);
        item.Top = poss;
        poss = (item.Top + item.Height + 10);
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addItem(txt.Text, false);
        Items.Add(txt.Text);
        txt.Text = "";
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) Устанавливаем Newtonsoft.Json

```
PM> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Version 10.0.3
```

2) Сериализуем ваш список в JSON так:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Items);
```