# Сериализация структур C#

Tags: c#, сериализация

Как сериализовать и десериализовать структуру Items?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    int i = 0;
    public struct Items
    {
        public string Text;
    };
    public Items[] Tasks = new Items[100];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    int poss = 10;

    public void addItem(string Text, bool Checked)
    {
        ToDo_Item item = new TestToDo.ToDo_Item(Text, Checked);
        visitor.Controls.Add(item);
        item.Top = poss;
        poss = (item.Top + item.Height + 10);
    }

    private void bunifuImageButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Tasks[i].Text = txt.Text;

        addItem(txt.Text, false);
        txt.Text = "";

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Convert.ToString(Tasks[i].Text);
        i++;            
    }
}
```

Comment: Какую именно сериализацию вы имеете в виду? Бинарную? XML? JSON?

Comment: Дубликат? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/730671/10105

Answer (score 1):

Для сериализации в JSON удобно пользоваться библиотекой [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

Установите в свой проект требуемый NuGet пакет `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`

Для сериализации нужно проделать следующее

```
//сериализуем
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context, Formatting.Indented);

try
{
    //пишем в файл
    File.WriteAllText(_pathToFile, json);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Ошибка сохранения в файл");
}
```

Для обратной процедуры (десериализации)

```
try
{
    //читаем файл
    string text = File.ReadAllText(_pathToFile);
    //десериализуем в объект
    Context context = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Context>(text);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Ошибка чтения из файла");
}
```

Comment: Пример заготовки такого приложения можете скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/qLC1SBQg3NkUs5)